# Custom action throwing 500 error while saving

Tags: marketing-automation

[image]

I created a custom action, followed all steps mentioned in https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/create-an-activity-type.html

i can see my custom action in the marketing editor, but when i try to save it, it throws 500 error.

**this is the response error:**

```
{
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
  "exceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
  "stackTrace": "   
at Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Extensions.AutomationPlanDefinitionViewModelExtensions.FindChild(AutomationActivityDefinitionViewModel parent, String pathKey, Guid exitActivityId, Int32 level)\r\n   
at Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Extensions.AutomationPlanDefinitionViewModelExtensions.GetActivities(IActivityDescriptorLocator activityDescriptorLocator, CultureInfo culture, IActivityConverterFactory`1 activityConverterFactory, BaseLog logger, Boolean activate, AutomationActivityDefinitionViewModel parentActivity, AutomationActivityDefinitionViewModel sibling, AutomationActivityDefinitionViewModel exitActivity)\r\n   
at Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Extensions.AutomationPlanDefinitionViewModelExtensions.ToDomainModel(AutomationPlanDefinitionViewModel viewModel, IActivityDescriptorLocator activityDescriptorLocator, CultureInfo culture, IActivityConverterFactory`1 activityConverterFactory, BaseLog logger, Boolean activate, DateTime createdAt, DateTime lastModifiedDate, IAutomationPlanDefinition existingPlan)\r\n   
at Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Data.AutomationPlanRepository.d__16.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Data.AutomationPlanRepository.d__15.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Sitecore.Marketing.Automation.Client.Controllers.AutomationPlansController.d__9.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the error in the screenshot `HTTP failure response for http://localhost:44001/sitecore/api/ma/plans/?CultureName=en: 500 Internal Server Error`, it seems like the sitecore language cookie is set to some other language and marketing automation API is trying to fetch all plans items in default language `en`. You can try clearing your cookies and cache of the browser or open the Sitecore marketing automation module in an incognito (private) window.